# Python pillow makes my JPGs 3 times larger

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, filesize

I'm using Pillow to manipulate some JPGs. When I save a manipulated JPG, it is three times the size of the original. I am only drawing three rectangles and adding a small text label on the image. Why is the resulting file, processed by Pillow, so much larger than the original? How can I get the size closer to the original?

Here's some version information, and a file listing so you can see some troubleshooting work that I've tried. File **image.jpg** is the original.

Versions and file listing:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 freeze | grep -i pil
Pillow==5.4.1
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
pi@raspberrypi:~ ll image*
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 106522 Jul  9 17:14 image2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 101431 Jul  9 17:14 imageconv.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  35873 Jul  9 03:15 image.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 104781 Jul  9 17:14 imageopt.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 138430 Jul  9 17:14 imageq85.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  35856 Jul  9 17:14 imageresaved.jpg
```

The file manipulation code:

```
def imageDecorate(event_dir, boxes):
    source_image = event_dir + "/image.jpg"
    dest_image = event_dir + "/image2.jpg"
    dest_image3 = event_dir + "/imageq85.jpg"
    dest_image4 = event_dir + "/imageopt.jpg"
    dest_image5 = event_dir + "/imageconv.jpg"
    dest_image6 = event_dir + "/imageresaved.jpg"
    if not isfile(source_image):
        return False
    base = Image.open(source_image).convert('RGBA')
    out3 = base.convert('CMYK')
    out4 = Image.open(source_image)

    # Draw rectangles and text label
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype("fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf", 12)
    for box in boxes:
        # Omitting irrelevant details. It's normal ImageDraw stuff ...
        draw.rectangle( [...])
        draw.rectangle( [...])
        draw.rectangle( [...])
        draw.text( [...] )
    out2 = base.convert('CMYK')

    # Write  to dest_image.
    out2.save(dest_image)   # image2 - manipulated image
    out2.save(dest_image3, quality=85)    # imageq85 - Expect it to be larger than image2
    out2.save(dest_image4, optimize=True) # imageopt - Expect it to be smaller than image2
    out3.save(dest_image5)  # imageconv - no editing, just convert -> RGBA -> CYMK
    out4.save(dest_image6)  # imageresaved - original image, resaved, no change

    return True
```

I find some clues in the file header, but I don't know enough about JPG files to understand and act on the clues.

Header for the original file:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ xxd image.jpg | head -20
00000000: ffd8 ffe0 0010 4a46 4946 0001 0100 0001  ......JFIF......
00000010: 0001 0000 ffdb 0043 0008 0606 0706 0508  .......C........
00000020: 0707 0709 0908 0a0c 140d 0c0b 0b0c 1912  ................
00000030: 130f 141d 1a1f 1e1d 1a1c 1c20 242e 2720  ........... $.'
00000040: 222c 231c 1c28 3729 2c30 3134 3434 1f27  ",#..(7),01444.'
00000050: 393d 3832 3c2e 3334 32ff db00 4301 0909  9=82<.342...C...
00000060: 090c 0b0c 180d 0d18 3221 1c21 3232 3232  ........2!.!2222
00000070: 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232  2222222222222222
00000080: 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232  2222222222222222
00000090: 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 3232 ffc0  22222222222222..
000000a0: 0011 0801 5102 5803 0122 0002 1101 0311  ....Q.X.."......
000000b0: 01ff c400 1f00 0001 0501 0101 0101 0100  ................
000000c0: 0000 0000 0000 0001 0203 0405 0607 0809  ................
000000d0: 0a0b ffc4 00b5 1000 0201 0303 0204 0305  ................
000000e0: 0504 0400 0001 7d01 0203 0004 1105 1221  ......}........!
000000f0: 3141 0613 5161 0722 7114 3281 91a1 0823  1A..Qa."q.2....#
00000100: 42b1 c115 52d1 f024 3362 7282 090a 1617  B...R..$3br.....
00000110: 1819 1a25 2627 2829 2a34 3536 3738 393a  ...%&'()*456789:
00000120: 4344 4546 4748 494a 5354 5556 5758 595a  CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZ
00000130: 6364 6566 6768 696a 7374 7576 7778 797a  cdefghijstuvwxyz
```

Header for the file **imageconv.jpg**, which was simply converted to RGBA and then back to CMYK:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ xxd imageconv.jpg | head -20
00000000: ffd8 ffee 000e 4164 6f62 6500 6400 0000  ......Adobe.d...
00000010: 0000 ffdb 0043 0008 0606 0706 0508 0707  .....C..........
00000020: 0709 0908 0a0c 140d 0c0b 0b0c 1912 130f  ................
00000030: 141d 1a1f 1e1d 1a1c 1c20 242e 2720 222c  ......... $.' ",
00000040: 231c 1c28 3729 2c30 3134 3434 1f27 393d  #..(7),01444.'9=
00000050: 3832 3c2e 3334 32ff c000 1408 0151 0258  82<.342......Q.X
00000060: 0443 1100 4d11 0059 1100 4b11 00ff c400  .C..M..Y..K.....
00000070: 1f00 0001 0501 0101 0101 0100 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0001 0203 0405 0607 0809 0a0b ffc4  ................
00000090: 00b5 1000 0201 0303 0204 0305 0504 0400  ................
000000a0: 0001 7d01 0203 0004 1105 1221 3141 0613  ..}........!1A..
000000b0: 5161 0722 7114 3281 91a1 0823 42b1 c115  Qa."q.2....#B...
000000c0: 52d1 f024 3362 7282 090a 1617 1819 1a25  R..$3br........%
000000d0: 2627 2829 2a34 3536 3738 393a 4344 4546  &'()*456789:CDEF
000000e0: 4748 494a 5354 5556 5758 595a 6364 6566  GHIJSTUVWXYZcdef
000000f0: 6768 696a 7374 7576 7778 797a 8384 8586  ghijstuvwxyz....
00000100: 8788 898a 9293 9495 9697 9899 9aa2 a3a4  ................
00000110: a5a6 a7a8 a9aa b2b3 b4b5 b6b7 b8b9 bac2  ................
00000120: c3c4 c5c6 c7c8 c9ca d2d3 d4d5 d6d7 d8d9  ................
00000130: dae1 e2e3 e4e5 e6e7 e8e9 eaf1 f2f3 f4f5  ................
```

Contents of **image.jpg**:
[image: original image]
File **imageconv.jpg** is identical in appearance to **image.jpg**.

Contents of **image2.jpg** (note, this example has 9 rects and 3 text labels):
[image: modified image]

Comment: `imageresaved.jpg` proves that it's not Pillow making the image bigger, it's the manipulations you've done before saving.  In particular it seems Pillow isn't able to optimize a CMYK image the same way it does RGB.

Comment: Mmmm. 1) You haven't provided any images - that's not very helpful when your question is about image processing. 2) You start with either a CMYK or RGB Image e (I don't know which because you didn't share it) then you make it RGBA for no apparent reason thereby increasing its size by 33% then make it CMYK which doesn't need A - so why did you introduce A in the first place? 3) What are actually trying to do? 4) What was the original quality setting and why do you think 85% quality will make a larger file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell 1-4) I was trying to avoid the "please do my homework for me" syndrome, mostly. 
1) I wasn't sure the images themselves were relevant. I'll add them to the problem statement.
2) My code was based on the example code at TutorialsPoint (link to follow). The example code did an alpha_composite() to combine two RGBA images.
3) Draw three rectangles and add a small text label on the image.
4) Per the Pillow docs, default quality is 75. File was created in another program, using pillow w/ default settings. Therefore I assume that 75 was the original quality setting.

Comment: TutorialsPoint example code at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pillow/python_pillow_imagedraw_module.htm. (I don't know if posting a link like this is allowed. Delete this comment if it isn't.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in the two convert() steps. They were entirely unnecessary.

I got enough clues from the comments, to try drawing directly on the image, rather than converting it to RGBA and then back to CMYK. I didn't know I could do that. File sizes are now more reasonable.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ll image*
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  38283 Jul 10 00:29 image2.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 101431 Jul 10 00:29 imageconv.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  35873 Jul  9 03:15 image.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  37363 Jul 10 00:29 imageopt.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  50024 Jul 10 00:29 imageq85.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi  35856 Jul 10 00:29 imageresaved.jpg
```

Revised code (troubleshooting images retained for comparison):

```
def imageDecorate(event_dir, boxes):
    source_image = event_dir + "/image.jpg"
    dest_image = event_dir + "/image2.jpg"
    dest_image3 = event_dir + "/imageq85.jpg"
    dest_image4 = event_dir + "/imageopt.jpg"
    dest_image5 = event_dir + "/imageconv.jpg"
    dest_image6 = event_dir + "/imageresaved.jpg"
    if not isfile(source_image):
        return False
    base = Image.open(source_image)
    out3 = base.convert('CMYK')
    out4 = Image.open(source_image)

    # Draw rectangles and text label
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(base)
    fnt = ImageFont.truetype("fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf", 12)
    for box in boxes:
        # Omitting irrelevant details. It's normal ImageDraw stuff ...
        draw.rectangle( [...])
        draw.rectangle( [...])
        draw.rectangle( [...])
        draw.text( [...] )

    # Write  to dest_image.
    base.save(dest_image)   # image2 - manipulated image
    base.save(dest_image3, quality=85)    # imageq85 - Expect it to be larger than image2
    base.save(dest_image4, optimize=True) # imageopt - Expect it to be smaller than image2
    out3.save(dest_image5)  # imageconv - no editing, just convert -> RGBA -> CYMK
    out4.save(dest_image6)  # imageresaved - original image, resaved, no change

    return True
```